# jQuery if document title indexof matches string

Tags: jquery, if-statement, indexof

So basically if document caption matches exactly, do something.

I am trying with `indexOf` but it keeps going on no matter what is the page title.

For example, on this very page, I  want it to go on only when document caption is **if statement - jQuery if document title indexof matches string - Stack Overflow** (which it is now):

```
if (document.title.indexOf("if statement - jQuery if document title indexof matches string - Stack Overflow") === -1){
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Just change your code to :

```
if (document.title.indexOf("if statement - jQuery if document title indexof matches string - Stack Overflow") != -1){
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");}
```

The indexOf method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs. so if is not -1 that means that contains the value.

Note: if you want an exact match use the "==" operator instead of indexOf

Cheers!